# Android error Login with twitter failure, failed to get request token

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, mobile

Has anyone else encountered this error before when trying to integrate twitter apis though Fabric? All i want to do is allow the user to sign in but whenever i click the twitter button it brings me to a white page and then gives me the error
failed to get request token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got the Solution of my Problem.

Actually I haven't add the callback url to the app on Twitter. That's why i am not getting the permitted Window.

Now i have added the url like http://myurl.com and now my problem solved.